# info.plist Uses

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anybody explain  me what is Info.plist in Resource folder..How  can i make use This in my app..?Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify different general resources and application configuration in Info.plist file like Application Icons, for all type of devices; supported device orientations; application version; application preferred language.
Check this out [PLIST documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/ConfigFiles.html)